# cant find element on website with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i want search five-stars hotels in the near of Stuttgart (Germany) automatically on hotelstars.eu and wrote a python script with the selenium framework. I looked for similar questions but nothing worked.

Here are my browser-Driver code in a seperate file (browserDriver.py):

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import os

from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito') 

chromedriver = r"\Users\simon\Documents\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

And the searchAutomattecally_hotelstars_eu.py - file:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

import browserDriver as bd
import time

val_land = 'Germany'
val_city = 'Stuttgart'
val_radius = '100'
val_stars = '5'



bd.driver.get('https://www.hotelstars.eu/de/deutschland/service/hotelsuche/')


bd.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# accept Cookies
bd.driver.find_element(By.ID, '564').click()

print('- - - Status: Cookies accepted')

element_land =bd.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'country')
print(element_land.text)

all_options = element_land.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'option')
for option in all_options:
    if option == val_land:
        select_land = Select(option)
        print('- - - Status: Geeeeeeeeeht')
print('- - - Status: if-Bedingung beendet')



select_land.select(By.Value, val_land)
print('- - - Status: ', select_land)


element_stadt = bd.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'city') 
element_stadt.send_keys(val_city)

element_radius = bd.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'radius') 
select_radius = Select(bd.driver.find_element_by_name('radius'))
select_radius.select_by_value(val_radius)


element_stars = bd.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'stars') 
select_stars = Select(bd.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'stars'))
select_stars.select_by_value(val_stars)

bd.driver.find_element_by_id("sendbtn").click()
```

link of the site [hotelstars.eu](https://www.hotelstars.eu/de/deutschland/service/hotelsuche/)

Here the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "...\searchAutomatecally_hotelstars_eu.py", line 28, in <module>
    element_land =bd.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'country')

File "...\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "...\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "...\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="country"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)
```

Can someone help??

Answer (score 0):

Cause the desired element is in this iframe :

```
<iframe id="searchIframe" scrolling="no" src="/fileadmin/bsdist/theme/modules/hotelstars_search/?L=1" width="100%" height="200px" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px; height: 250px;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

so you have to switch to this iframe first and then you can interact with the desired element.

```
bd.switch_to.frame(bd.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='searchIframe']"))
```

and then interact with country drop down like this :-

```
element_land = bd.driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'country')
```